# When does the following inequality hold valid: $n-\phi(n)\le \phi(n)+2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n\notin \{p,p^2,pq\}$ where $p,q$ are primes, when does the following inequality hold valid:

$n-\phi(n)\le \phi(n)+2$

In order for $n-\phi(n)\le \phi(n)+2$ to hold we must $n\le 2(\varphi(n)+1)$.

If we take $n=p^3$, then $2(\phi(n)+1)=2(p^3-p^2+1)$ and hence the inequality holds.
But how do I find all $n\in \mathbb N$ for which this inequality holds.

Can soomeone please help.

Comment: Are $\phi$ and $\varphi$ both the Euler totient function? Do you know that $\phi(n)=n\cdot\prod_{p\mid n\text{ prime}}\left(1-\frac 1p\right)$? And using this, can you say something about all $n$ with $n\le 2\phi(n)$?

Comment: @Mastrem; yes they are same

Comment: @Mastrem; i do know the expression you have given for $\phi(n)$ but i dont think i am able to proceed from that expression and figure out all such n. Can you please give an answer

Comment: Is there a reason to think there is a characterization of all such $n$?

Answer (score 1):

The question is for which $n$ we have
$$
\frac{n-2}{2}\le \phi(n).
$$
There are infinitely many $n\ge 1$ satisfying this, for example $n=p$ prime as you said. However, there are also infinitely many not satisfying it, e.g., for $n=6k$, with $k$ such that $\gcd(6,k)=1$ and $k\ge 2$ we have $2\phi(k)< 3k-1$ and hence
$$
\phi(n)=\phi(6k)=\phi(6)\cdot \phi(k) =2\phi(k) <
3k-1=\frac{n-2}{2}.  
$$
I leave it to you, to exclude other possible $n$-s as well.

Comment: Is there any tricky way to do this problem?  I understand doing it case by case is a way out, but that will be very cumbersome, I posted this problem with an intention to get a smarter way

Comment: The "smarter" way is for you. I wanted to help with examples, which already show that  it is not clear that a general "smart" characterisation is possible. What is the source of this question? From a contest? Then of course it is likely that there is a nice characterisation. But contest questions should not be answered here.