# Find conditions on $p,q,r$ such that $n-\phi(n)>\phi(n)+(p+q-1)?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I am stuck on the following problem:

**If $n=pqr$ where $p<q<r$ are primes, find conditions on $p,q,r$ such that $n-\phi(n)>\phi(n)+(p+q-1)?$**

**My try**:
Since $n=pqr$ so,

$n-\phi(n)-\phi(n)+(p+q-1)=n-2\phi(n)+(p+q-1)$

$= pqr-2\phi(pqr)-p-q+1$

$=pqr-2(pqr-qr-pr-pq+p+q+r-1)-p-q+1$

$=-pqr+2qr+2pr+2pq-3p-3q-2r+3$

I am unable to proceed further.
Can someone please help me out on how to find condition on primes $p,q,r$ such that the inequality holds.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356815/when-does-the-following-inequality-hold-valid-n-phin-le-phin2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final expression may be rewritten as $(2-p)(2-q)(2-r)+p+q+2r-5$. [Note: The product $(2-p)(2-q)(2-r)$ is chosen so that the third and second degree terms come out right. The remaining terms adjust things so as to get the right expression.]

Case 1: If $p=2$ (and $q,r$ are larger primes), then the expression above is clearly positive.

Case 2: If $p=3$, the expression becomes
$$\begin{array}{lcl}  -(2-q)(2-r)+3+q+2r-5&=&-qr+2q+2r-4+3+q+2r-5\\
&=&-qr+3q+4r-6\\&=&-(q-4)(r-3)+6  \end{array}$$

For the permissible values ($q\ge 5, r\ge 7, r>q$), this is positive for $q=5,r=7$ and negative for all other possibilities.

Case 3: If $p\ge 5$, we have (noting that $q\ge 7, r\ge 11$)
$$\begin{array}{lcl}  (2-p)(2-q)(2-r)+p+q+2r-5&\le&-3(2-q)(2-r)+p+q+2r-5\\
&=&-3qr+6q+6r-12+p+q+2r-5\\&=&-3qr+p+7q+8r-17\\&\le &-3qr+8q+8r-17
\\ &<& -3qr+9q+9r-17 \\&=&-3(q-3)(r-3)+10 \\&<& 0 \end{array}$$
So in case 3, the expression is always negative.